# Bezier Curve TILT exporting

Tags: bezier-curves

I am currently in the process of creating a rollercoaster outside of Blender, but I am using Blender to build a path for my coaster.

I currently made my Bezier Curve along my imported Coaster. I added TILT value's to the bezier curve itself, now I have the following issue.

I am currently using .obj to export my bezier curve. This gives me about ~16000 positions which are really awesome and I am able to use them in my rollercoaster, however. I cant seem to find a way to export TILT. The only way I found was exporting TILT on the control points of the curve itself.

Would anyone be able to help me with this? would be awesome!

Comment: The tilt part of the bezier curve is not really a native property of bezier curves. .obj are know to be limited they usually store only basic data and it's possible that obj format is not able to strore this part of the information. I think that you should find another format to export it, but it will be difficult to suggest you something if you dont tell us where you want to the curve. You can alsotry to change the export parametter on the bottom left when exporting to see if some parametter could help you to export those curve, maybe with write normals and write nurbs.